# Forced Duffing equation $\ddot x +x+\varepsilon(bx^3+k \dot x+ax−F\cos(t))=0$ bifurcation analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, bifurcation, nonlinear-dynamics

For the forced Duffing oscillator in the limit where the forcing, detuning, damping, and nonlinearity are all weak:
$$\ddot x +x+\varepsilon(bx^3+k \dot x+ax−F\cos(t))=0$$
where $0<\varepsilon<<1$, $b>0$ is the nonlinearity, $k>0$ is the damping, $a$ is the detuning,
and $F>0$ is the forcing strength. This system deals with saddle-node bifurcations of cycles arise in its analysis. The averaged equations of this system are
$$r'=-\frac{1}{2}(kr+\sin(\phi)) \\\phi'=-\frac{1}{8}(4a-br^2+\frac{4F}{r}\cos(\phi))$$
Show that fixed
points for the averaged system correspond to phase-locked periodic solutions for the original forced oscillator. Show further that saddle-node bifurcations of fixed
points for the averaged system correspond to saddle-node bifurcations of cycles
for the oscillator.

So far, all I have done is find the fixed points of the averaged system, which occur when
$$r=\frac{-F}{k}\sin(\phi)\\\phi=2\pi c-\cos^{-1}(\frac{r(3br^2-4a)}{4F})$$
I don't exactly know how to show that these correspond to phase-locked periodic solutions for the original Duffing oscillator, though. Even more, I struggle to understand how I can classify the fixed points of the averaged equations as saddle-node bifurcations. I found that the Jacobian $J$ of the averaged system is$$J=\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}k & -\frac{1}{2}cos(\phi)\\\frac{1}{4}br-\frac{4F}{8}\ln
|r|\cos(\phi) & \frac{F}{2r}\sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
but this seems way too complicated to be a good way to classify these fixed points. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no reason to try to analytically find the fixed points of the phase-locked periodic solutions. Instead, recognize that at the fixed points of the average system, $r'=\phi '=0$. This means the radius is constant and the angular velocity is constant, so this corresponds to a closed orbit being swept out at some constant period. Thus, what you're left with is phase-locked periodic solutions in the original system. Similarly, for saddle-node bifurcations of the averaged system, this must mean two limit cycles are colliding and annihilating each other in the original system, and you then have a saddle-node bifurcation of cycles by defintion.